# RefererNotAllowedMapError when running locally

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I am trying to run my project locally and connect with the google places API, but I am getting the following response:

Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:8888/

I understand that it is being required for me to provide a authorization for an URL on cloud plattform, but how am I suppose to do so when running locally?

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same issue. It requires a credit card to be attached.